# Question on capacitance between two parallel cylinders

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

We are asked to prove that the capacitance of two infinitely long 
 uniformly charged conductors with coaxial cylindrical surfaces is given by 
\begin{equation}
C= \dfrac{2\pi\epsilon_0L}{\mathrm{ln}\left(\dfrac{b}{a}\right)}
\end{equation}

Now, I was successful in proving the relation but I have a conceptual doubt.

**Doubt:** If the the inner cylinder was hollow (It was solid in the given problem), would the capacitance be different?

My guess: I guess it won't be different. Because the capacitance depends on the potential *between* the surfaces and does not care what happens beyond the surfaces.

Is this reasoning correct? If not, please explain where is this logic flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For conductors all excess charge resides on the surface. Therefore, if your conductor was hollow the charge distribution would not be any different than if you had a solid cylindrical conductor. Your results will not be any different.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @NirmalPadwal Glad I could help